# The height of a section of overlapping circles.

Tags: geometry, circles

Say I have two identical circles, both of radii of one, overlapping, as shown in the diagram below:

[image: Circle Diagram]

In this diagram, *x* is the circumference of the circles, and the bit of the bottom circle which is drawn blue (the overlapping bit) is $1/6$th of the whole circumference.

What I'm looking for is *y*, which is this:

[image: Circle Diagram 2.0]

Now, working out *x* is easy - it's $2\pi r$, thus the overlapping bit is $1/3\pi r$. But how do I proceed in finding *y* from here? Help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You can use the ratio of the overlap to the circumference to get the angle of the sector. Then it's a matter of trigonometry with a right angled triangle to get the length.

Answer (score 1):

If we draw a straight line between the two points of intersection, we have two [circular segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) joined at the bases.

The height $h$ of one of the circular segments is

$$h = R(1 - \cos (\theta/2))$$

where $\theta$ is the central angle and $R$ is the radius of the circle.

Can you take it from here?

Spoiler:

> The central angle subtending the blue arc is the same as the angular measure of the arc, which is $\pi/3$. Taking $R=1$, the height of one of the circular segments is $h = 1 - \cos(\pi/6),$ or $h = 1 - (\sqrt{3}/2).$ Then, $y=2-\sqrt{3}.$

Comment: yeah, just double $h$, thanks. But I am a bit confused about the 'central angle' thing. And where does the $1/6x$ get plugged in here?

Comment: There's a (simple) relation between the blue curve and the central angle.

Comment: wait, i'm still confused as to what exactly the central angle is.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralAngle.html

Comment: ok i see that, but i don't see how that applies here. I realise the formula needs it, but I don't see how the blue curve is related to that.

Comment: They are equal.

Comment: Well, I figured out that $h=0.133975$, but I need an *exact* value. How do I get that from this?

Comment: I'm guessing you used your calculator? If so, you should review your trigonometry and learn some of the values for $\sin , \cos$, etc. I put a spoiler in my answer.